# como extraer datos radiobutton en ts para llevarlo a la base de datos

Tags: php, angular, ionic, programación-móvil, backend

Saludos tengo un proyecto en el cual tengo todo funcionando correctamente la app es sencilla contiene un CRUD donde registro la informacion que deseo y luego al realizar un click en esa informacion abre un modal donde por radiobuttons puedo seleccionar algo que quiero asignarle a esos datos agregados para que en la otra ventana aparesca el Id del dato agregado junto con la seleccion del radiobutton, pero me he estancado en la segunda parte para trabajar con el radio button tengo el backend hecho solo en php sin framework el registro funciona solo es el radio button que quiero hacer que trabaje para guardar ese dato dejare una imagenes para que sea mas entendible lo que quiero hcacer imagen 1. Aqui es cuando realizo el registro, imagen 2. aqui me muestra los datos del registro para asignarle un estado por medio del radiobutton, imagen 3. aqui es donde deberia de aparecer tanto el estado como el numero del vehiculo o el id

[image]

[image]

[image]

y aqui es donde quiero que el radio button envie el valor y haga el cambio siempre que sea al mismo id del registro. al final le dejo parte del codigo tanto del backend y el ts del radiobutton.
codigo php backend

```html
`if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] ==='GET')
   {
      
    if(isset($_GET['Id_Estado']))
    {//id userd to fetch single row
        $id = $conect ->real_escape_string($_GET['Id_Estado']);
        $sql = $conect ->query("SELECT * FROM estado WHERE Id_Estado '$id'");
        $data = $sql ->fetch_assoc();
    }else 
    {//fetch all rows
        $data = array();
        $sql = $conect ->query("SELECT * FROM estados");
        while ($x = $sql -> fetch_assoc())
        {
            $data[] =$x;
        }
    }
    exit(json_encode($data)); //return Json data
    
   }
   
   if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']==='POST')
   {
    $data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));
    $sql = $conect ->query ("INSERT INTO estados (Estados)VALUES ('".$data ->Estado."')");
    if($sql)
    {
        $data->id = $conect->insert_id;
        exit(json_encode($data));
    }else
    {
        exit(json_encode(array('status'=> 'error')));
    }
   }
   
   if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']==='PUT')
   {
    if(isset($_GET['Id_Estados']))
    {
        $id = $conect->real_escape_string($_GET['Id_Estados']);
        $data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));
        $sql = $conect->query("UPDATE estado SET  estado = '".$data ->estado."' WHERE Id_Estados = '$id'");
        if($sql)
        {
            exit(json_encode(array('status' => 'success')));
        }
        else
        {
            exit(json_encode(array('status' => 'error')));
        }
    }
      }
   
   if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']==='DELETE')
   {
    if(isset($_GET['Id_Estados']))
    {
        $id = $conect ->real_escape_string($_GET['Id_Estados']);
        $sql = $conect->query("DELETE FROM estado WHERE Id_Estados = '$id'");

        if($sql)
        {
            exit(json_encode(array('status' => 'success')));

        }   
        else 
        {
            exit(json_encode(array('status' => 'error')));
            
        }
    }
   
   }
   
?>`
```

codigo ts

```js
 optins:string
 optionschanges(){
   alert(this.options);
 }
  CloseStatus(){
    this.modal.dismiss(null, 'closed')
  }

  
 

  SendEstado(){
   }//Boton para realizar el envio
  
}
```

Comment: Agrega el archivo `.ts` de donde deseas sacar el valor, debe guardarse en el modelo. Para sacarnos de dudas agrega lo que te pido.

Comment: me dices el archivo ts a odnde quier enviar el valor de los radiobutton, porque el que puse es el archivo ts del mismo modal que tiene los radiobutton